# Trying to filter a list to bring back lines with a specific word

Tags: python-2.7

I just started learning python a week ago and am stuck on this exercise.  I had to read in a csv file of employees and there salaries and return a list with lines splitted at the tab.  The list looks like this:

```
employees = [['ID','Title','Salary','Base'],
             ['453334','Professor','0.56','.40'],
             ['4353434','Tutor','0.66','0065'.....]]
```

I have to filter the list to only keep those employees who are professors.  I know that I need something that prints those items where the column 4 value == "Professor". Here's what I have so far:

```
employees2 = []
def professor(x):
    for line in x:
       if x[?][4] == "Professor":
          employee2.append(line)
    return employee2
```

I just have no idea how to get it to look at every row, and only column 4 to output a list only keep those with the title or professor.

Comment: Why column 4? The `title` field is column 2, which makes it index 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
def professor(x):
    employees2 = []
    for line in x:
       if line[1] == "Professor":
          employees2.append(line)
    return employees2
```

The shorter (and more pythonic way) is:

```
employees2 = [line for line in employees if line[1] == "Professor"]
```

If you have to make a function:

```
def professor(x):
    return [line for line in x if line[1] == "Professor"]
```

Or (and someone will probably shout at me for this):

```
professor = lambda x: [line for line in x if line[1] == "Professor"]
```